# How to display links for an entire level (all pages) in a TYPO3 menu?

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I am trying to display all pages in the root level inside my menu.

I use:

```
special = list
special.value = 1, 2, 3, 4
```

This displays all my current pages but when adding new pages I will have to manually add them in the code.

Is there a way to automatically display all the pages in my root level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general you would use no `special` in your menu.

```
temp.mainMenu = HMENU
temp.mainMenu {
    1 = TMENU
    1 {
       NO {
          :
       }
       ACT {
          :
       }
    }
}
```

this will render the main menu on top level.
if you have one root page and the mainmenu consists of the pages one level deeper you might vary it with

```
temp.mainMenu.entryLevel = 1
```

Have a look into the [documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/ContentObjects/Hmenu/Index.html) for further options.

Answer (score 0):

This can also be done using

`special = directory
 special.value = 1`

Where 1 is the root page, every subpage under that page will be displayed.
Hope this helps.